# Symfony - Validate EntityType (or IntegerType) without original data (custo dropdown field)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, elasticsearch

I am confronted to a problem in Symfony 3 that is driving me crazy and I do not find any solutions. I have two entities "Advert" and "City". An advert must have a city. Like this :

```js
class Advert
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="adverts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 *
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $location;
```

In my database, there is 36000 cities. So, when I use an EntityType for my form (to create an advert), Symfony generates a big query with 36000 `<li>` and my page is slow to load.

```js
class AdvertType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('location',       EntityType::class, array(
                'class'        => 'AQDPlatformBundle:City',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple'     => false,
            ))
    }
}
```

My goal is to build myself the dropdown with an AJAX request and ElasticSearch (FOSElasticaBundle). I have already my request and it works. But, how to link creating advert, input fied and a "custom Type" (which could correspond to IntegerType for an id of City) ?

Comment: If I have correctly understood your question, not sure 100% tho. I think you should take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html The 3rd part should be what you aim to do

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't think about it but it can still be used. I did not want a dynamic relationship between two "select" fields but a link between a type of search engine and an entity.

Finally, I found what I wanted with Data Transformer : http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: @Julien it would be most helpful if you could post your solution with some code.